# NVidia driver not working Ubuntu18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia

Laptop - Lenovo thinkpad P52
uname -a

```
Linux ivan-ThinkPad-P52 5.1.3-050103-generic #201905161442 SMP Thu May 16 18:44:30 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

sudo lshw -c video

```
 *-display                 
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: GP107GLM [Quadro P1000 Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
   resources: irq:160 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff memory:70000000-71ffffff ioport:2000(size=128) memory:a4080000-a40fffff


*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:158 memory:604a000000-604affffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

/etc/default/grub

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=! acpi_osi='Windows2009'"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001CBBsv000017AAsd0000225Fbc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
driver   : nvidia-driver-410 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-396 - third-party free
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-430 - third-party free recommended
driver   : nvidia-driver-415 - third-party free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

I tried installing drivers (multiple versions) using this tutorial https://www.mvps.net/docs/install-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-lts-bionic-beaver-linux/

I also tried using `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` and removing any drivers before using `sudo apt purge nvidia*` (I ensured none drivers were there when typed `dpkg -l | grep nvidia`)

If I have Hybrid graphics enabled in BIOS, I can see valid nvidia-smi output, however laptor uses integrated graphics card Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (Coffeelake 3x8 GT2)

If I set Discrete graphics card, the nvidia-smi returns

```
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

and also in `nvidia-settings` I see only blank page.
How should I please set up nvidia driver?

Comment: The manual installation of nvidia drivers worked for me. I hope it helps you! See: [Installing NVIDIA drivers for Ubuntu 18.04](http://%20https//medium.com/@iamdibakardipu/how-i-fixed-my-display-resolution-by-installing-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux-489563052f6c)

Comment: that worked, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was answered by https://askubuntu.com/users/757577/moosee333 in the comment

> The manual installation of nvidia drivers worked for me. I hope it helps you! See: Installing NVIDIA drivers for Ubuntu 18.04 – moosee333 May 22 at 1:45